# Quick Settings drop-down and fragment lifecycle callbacks

Tags: android, android-fragments, settings

In my app, I need to do some action when the Quick Settings drop-down is opened and closed. For example, I need to check the internet and refresh the contents of a Fragment when the user turn on WiFi from the Quick Settings drop-down. In this case, which lifecycle callback method is called in the Fragment while the Quick Settings drop-down is opened and closed.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I needed to run some code after the quick settings was accessed. Unfortunately, `onResume()` in my experience did not get called when the quick settings is dismissed.

Instead, I did an override of the activity's [Activity.onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)) method. I stored the value as LiveData and observed it in the fragment.

The one caveat I found was that I was using an alert dialog in my fragment. This also causes the `Activity.onWindowFocusChanged` to be called with `false`. Aside from handling that edge case, it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

When Quick Settings dorp-down is opened Your activity will be

(Activity)onPause(); ---------- >(Fragment) onStop(); --------> (Activity) onStop();

When Quick Settings dorp-down is closed Your activity will be from

(Activity) onStop();------> (Activity) onRestart(); -------->(Activity) onStart();---->

(Fragment)onStart();------>(Activity)onResume();------>(Fragment)onResume();

I hope it is clear but if you dont understand it you see this photo. [image]